# How to move or draggable the child window page in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

```cs
private void DraggableBorder_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        var currentPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(DraggableBorder).Position;
        Point offset = new Point(currentPosition.X - startPoint.X, currentPosition.Y - startPoint.Y);

        if (_AppWindow == null)
        {
            _AppWindow = GetAppWindow();
        }

        _AppWindow.Move(new Windows.Graphics.PointInt32 { X = Convert.ToInt32(offset.X), Y = Convert.ToInt32(offset.Y) });

    }
}
```

In this case we can able to move the child window page. But it is blink and not set in the correct pointer position.

Comment: I test the [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/appwindow/), when the window moves, no flickering occurs.
I suggest you could refer to the offical sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/AppWindow/cs/Scenario5_RelativePositioning.xaml.cs#L77